# securing awstats with htaccess

Tags: awstats

I'm trying to configure awstats in a way that I have a site that is not authenticated, and another site that is authenticated.
More specifically
domain/awstats/awstats.pl?config=*X* **shouldn't** be authenticated
domain/awstats/awstats.pl?config=*Y* **should be** authenticated

after a lot of searching I haven't found any solution due to the fact that this is query-string related.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265944/apache-password-protect-specific-url

Answer (score 3):

Off the top of my head, here's one way you could do it.  Start by putting `awstats` on a virtual host that only listens to localhost...

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
...
</VirtualHost>
```

*Inside* that virtual host, include `RewriteRules` that translate path-based URLs into the appropriate query strings:

```
RewriteRule /awstats/config/(.*) /awstats/awstats.pl?config=$1
```

With this in place, you can access:

```
/awstats/awstats.pl?config=X
```

Using:

```
/awstats/config/X
```

But note that, at the moment, this is all available only via `localhost`.  We haven't yet established external connectivity.  For that, we're going to put `<Location>` blocks in your main server config that will:

- Implement the necessary access controls
- Proxy requests to the "internal" virtual host

Like this:

```
<Location /awstats/config/X>
  ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/awstats/config/X
</Location>

<Location /awstats/config/Y>
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "awstats X"
  AuthBasicProvider file
  AuthUserFile /path/to/htpasswd
  require valid-user

  ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/awstats/config/Y
</Location>
```

This is all off-the-cuff, so it's entirely possible that there are some errors here, but the basic idea is sound.

Comment: Great post, and should work. But appareantly, my company does not allow rewrites to localhost. Even though, I had the best results as of yet, so you do earn some credit.